# ABBYY cloud ocr - converting to text

Tags: php, ocr, typeconverter

I tried the conversion to text with this: http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/processImage?language=english&exportFormat=txt

the funny thing is the result produced is different.

When I code it to have the output into a .txt file & download it, I see more contents on it that if I have them output on the browser. any reason for that?

I am using the php sample from the site here http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/code-samples/PHP.zip.

any idea where went wrong?

Comment: Page not found on your first link. Maybe they just blocked my IP? Please check the link or do I need to log-in first.

Comment: that's not a page. its the url where we submit with the api